# Como bloquear para que o CSS não altere além de Footer e Header

Tags: php, html, css

Queria saber se posso bloquear o CSS para um local específico.

**Vejam o seguinte:**
Criei um sistema onde cada usuário vai definir o próprio `Header` e `Footer` (consequentemente seu próprio css). Porém gostaria que ao ler os CSSs o arquivo do meu cliente não tivesse efeito sobre o meu. Exemplo, Se ele copiar algum elemento do HTML e quiser mudar, ele não poderia.

Sei que isso é possível, pois no Wordpress dá pra fazer. Mas eu não sei como fazer isso.

**Obs.:** Eu tentei usar o `iframe`, mas fica inviável, devido o nosso sistema ser responsivo, não consigo fazer o `iframe` acompanhar o tamanho do `header` ou `footer` que vai diminuindo cada vez que dá um `resize` na tela.

Obrigado

Comment: Carregue o do usuário antes do seu, defina classes e ids com prefixos bem característicos, e use !important nas suas coisas (não deixa de ser gambiarra). Se seu CSS vier depois do dele, e as suas diretivas tiverem **especificidade** maior, as suas valerão.

Comment: Será que não compensa criar um cookie para armazenar as configurações de css do cliente ? evita esse tipo de problema e torna o sistema mais customizável.

Comment: Obrigado Bacco, mas mesmo assim, se ele usa um atributo que no meu não tem definido o dele vai valer. Aí a gambiarra não vinga...

Comment: Não entendo de Cookie Gabriel, vou pesquisar. Obrigado

Answer (score 1):

A forma mais fácil é você pegar o CSS definido pelo  usuário e encapsular com o seletor header|footer (caso sejam exatamente estes os que você está usando) através do seu próprio código. Assim se você tem um estrutura `<header id="header">...</header><qualquercoisa>...</qualquercoisa><footer id="footer">...</footer>` e o user define uma série de rules, digamos numa textarea para o header:

```
color: red;
position: fixed;
h1 {
    rules...;
}
```

seu código recebe essas regras e transforma em

```
header#header {
  color: red;
  position: fixed;
}
header#header h1 {
    rules...;
}
```

Caso o user coloque algum seletor como `header h1 {` você remove o "header" antes.

Como essa estratégia você garante que o CSS do usuário não vai afetar nada fora os locais que você permitir pois não existem parent selectors (seletores para apontar a um elemento níveis acima na DOM) em CSS.

Obs: Caso você queira considerar CSS4, que ainda é uma padrão em criação, teria que lidar com os novos seletores de parent elements, neste caso seria necessário remover todos eles do CSS definido pelo usuário para evitar que ele possa ter acesso a toda a sua DOM.